# Angular 6 add input on enter key

Tags: angular

I have component called `text-editor.component` and this is my html template:

```
<div class="container">

<div id="testo" class="offset-1 text-center" >
  <input type="text" class="col-8 text-center">
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a new input text when I press the enter key. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div id="testo" class="offset-1 text-center" >
  <input type="text" class="col-8 text-center">
  <!-- second input -->
  <input type="text" class="col-8 text-center">
 </div>
</div>
```

when the user presses enter after inputting text into the input, a new input should spawn. I am using Angular's template driven forms.

Comment: How many inputs do you need? Just one after the first?

Comment: What have you done so far to handle the event from hitting [enter key](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter)? You need to clarify if this event needs to be tied to an input, or if you are trying to capture enter at the document/body level. Also you need to clarify whether you are using template driven forms or reactive forms as well as how you plan/expect to store data from each input.

Comment: @SiddAjmera not only one. usually I do these kind of things with jQuery, now what I can do is add (keyup.enter)="onEnter()" on input but I want to know if there is a easy way to achieve this result with angular

Comment: There's a Typical way of using a Reactive FormArray and then pushing new `FormControl`s to the `FormArray` on `enter`

Plus, it's not really advisible using jQuery when you're already using Angular that has everything that jQuery has to offer.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can approach this using [Reactive Forms FormArray](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays). You would attach an `(keyup)` or `(keyup.enter)` handler to the `<input />`. Within the handler for this `keyup` event, we push a new `FormControl` to a `FormArray`. This example uses [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) to generate a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) that contains a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) with a key of `things`. We use the [push](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#push) method of `FormArray` to add a new `FormControl`/`AbstractControl` within the handler for keyup.

Component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
    
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  myForm: FormGroup;
    
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }
    
    
  onEnter() {
    this.addThing();
  }
    
  get things() {
    return this.myForm.get('things') as FormArray;
  }
    
  private createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      things: this.fb.array([
        // create an initial item
        this.fb.control('')
      ])
    });
  }
    
  private addThing() {
    this.things.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
}
```

Template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div formArrayName="things">
        <div *ngFor="let thing of things.controls; let i=index">
            <label [for]="'input' + i">Thing {{i}}:</label>
            <input type="text" [formControlName]="i" [name]="'input' + i" [id]="'input' + i" (keyup.enter)="onEnter()"  />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

At a very basic level you can loop through each in the form array using the [controls](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#controls) property of the respective `FormArray` element and the value using the [value](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value) property:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let thing of things.controls">{{thing.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5zmbg) demonstrating the functionality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56125026/8662236
can you please look into this.

Answer (score 44):

Controller

Declare an array 'inputs' and initialises it with a value of 1.

```
inputs = [1];
```

Create a function addInput().

```
addInput() {
  this.inputs.push(1);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="testo" class="offset-1 text-center" *ngFor="let more of inputs">
<input type="text" class="col-8 text-center" (keyup.enter)="addInput()">
</div>
```

In your template you'll be calling the addInput() function every time you hit enter (keyup.enter). The function pushes a new value into the array, whose length increases by 1 and that in turn creates a new input field.

Answer (score 29):

You can easily use keydown event in angular 6, angular 7, angular 8 and angular 9... applications.

When user will key up on input box field then trigger onKeyDownEvent() of angular component. You can use (keydown.enter) attribute as to call function. Bellow logic code:

.html

```
<input type="search" (keydown.enter)="onKeyDownEvent($event)" />
```

.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']

})
export class MyComponent {

  
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  onKeyDownEvent(event: any) {
    this.router.navigate(['search-result'], { relativeTo: this.route });
    ...logic

  }
}
```

Be aware that we need to navigate to other route programmatically, in the .ts file, NOT in html file with the routerLink="/search-result" . We need to inject Router and ActivatedRoute classes as to navigate from current route to the /search-result route.

Answer (score 4):

I see a lot people using either keyup.enter or keydown.enter, but what is most appropriate is keypress.enter

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="reference_num" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Reference number" name="reference_num" (keypress.enter)="search()">
```

Comment: 'keypress' does not work for me. Used instead 'keydown' or 'keyup'.

Comment: @DDimitrov what version of angular CLI?

Comment: CLI version 11.0.6

Comment: @DDimitrov  can we see your code. just exactly like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keydown-enter , everything should work.

Comment: nope, `keypress` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event